# Web Scraping with Python - Restart a Spider before finish

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I'm working with a spider on Python to scrape some text from a web. I have to type a word, push enter and then the spider starts. I need to know if exist a way to restart the spider when it finish before closing, for example:
I pass some word, the spider scrapes the information, when finish it return to the beginning and ask me to type another word, and so on.

This is my code:

spider.py:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Spider
from verbos.items import MercadoItem


class MercadoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'verbos'
allowed_domain = ['www.pt.bab.la']
print("Ingrese un verbo:")
variable = input()
start_urls = ['https://pt.bab.la/verbo/portugues/' + variable]

eu_xpaths = (
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', 
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    ' //*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'
    )
tu_xpaths= (
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'
    )
voce_xpaths= (
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()',
    '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'
    )
nos_xpaths= (
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[4]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[4]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[4]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[4]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[4]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'
)
voces_xpaths= (
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[6]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[5]/div[6]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[6]/div[6]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@id="conjFull"]/div[2]/div/div[8]/div[6]/div[2]/text()',
'//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[6]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[6]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()', '//*[@class="content-column"]/div[5]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/text()'
)
campos = ("eu", "tu", "voce", "nos", "voces")


def parse(self, response):

       response.selector.remove_namespaces()

       for xpaths in zip (self.eu_xpaths, self.tu_xpaths, self.voce_xpaths, self.nos_xpaths, self.voces_xpaths):
           data = [response.xpath(xpath).getall() for xpath in xpaths]
           yield {campo: valor for campo, valor in zip(self.campos, data)}
```

settings.py:

```
BOT_NAME = 'verbos'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['verbos.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'verbos.spiders'

ITEM_PIPELINES = {'verbos.pipelines.MercadoPipeline': 200}

FEED_FORMAT = "csv"
FEED_URI = 'verbos_items.csv'
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING='cp1252'

ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
```

Thank you!

Comment: You could use `subprocess` to call `scrapy crawl <spider>` with the required arguments from your command-line interface.

Comment: that's worked! thank you very very much!!